# How to expand the Array in the response of Get Metric Data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to read an existing metric from cloudwatch

```
var params = {
        EndTime: moment().unix(),
        StartTime: moment().subtract(7, 'days').unix(),
        MetricDataQueries: [ 
            {
                Id: 'e1',
                Expression: 'SORT(SEARCH("{Costs,Studentname} MonthlySpent", "Sum", 7200), MAX, DESC)',
                Label: 'Weekly Spend Per Student',
            },
        ],
    };
```

The response obtained looks like:

```
{
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '9d05bb61-30b0-448c-a64f-4362c6527ea0' },
  MetricDataResults: [
    {
      Id: 'e1',
      Label: 'Weekly Spend Per Student  - mary',
      Timestamps: [Array],
      Values: [Array],
      StatusCode: 'Complete',
      Messages: []
    },
    {
      Id: 'e1',
      Label: 'Weekly Spend Per Student - nancy',
      Timestamps: [Array],
      Values: [Array],
      StatusCode: 'Complete',
      Messages: []
    },  
],
  Messages: []
}
```

Could someone point out why I am receiving the values as [Array] and is there a way retrieve the correct SUM value for each student?

And instead of reading multiple results (timestamp and Value Array),
is it possible to only see one timestamp and one value in the response?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(response)` if you are printing the response out using `console.log`. So: `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: Thanks. However, Why is it an array? I just wanted the result for the given time range. ie; 1 timestamp and 1 value